# How to test ngAfterViewInit

Tags: angular, testing, karma-jasmine

I want to test ngAfterviewInit() , how can i test this method by using jasmine-karma

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.input.valueChanges.pipe(debounceTime(1000),distinctUntilChanged()).subscribe((delayVal)=>{
      if(delayVal!=undefined){
        this.inputValue = delayVal;
        console.log("delay",delayVal); 
        this.searchData(this.inputValue);
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to test? If it's executing the function only, `fixture.detectChanges()` inside your test should trigger this function once during the component lifecycle.

Comment: add a spy to `searchData` and check to see if it gets executed.

Comment: off-topic: `typeof delayVal !== 'undefined'` is better than `delayVal!=undefined` because without the `typeof`, a variable that doesn't exist will throw an error instead of returning a string.

Answer (score 0):

`ngAfterViewInit()` is called by Angular automatically during the initial change detection, so:

```
fixture.detectChanges();
```